# my react native project is running good on npx react-native start --reset-cache but its giving error while npx react-native run-android..?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-firebase

**Unable to load script.Make sure you are either running a Metro server or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release**

```
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^18.6.1",
"@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^18.6.1",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.9",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.6",
"@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.17",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.72.6",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.12.0",
"react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
"react-native-reanimated": "^3.3.0",
"react-native-root-siblings": "^5.0.1",
"react-native-root-toast": "^3.5.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.6.3",
"react-native-screens": "^3.22.0",
"react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.7",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.1"
```

I have tried literraly every solution but the problem is still same